# AWS EFS: How to browse file?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, devops

I have this EFS mount mounted on couple of my servers. It's about 4.3TB now.

Unfortunately the directory structure is not done properly which is why it takes forever to load certain big folders using the usual OS file navigation commands.

This got me thinking that I must not be the only one facing this issue. However, I couldn't find anything out there that solves this...yet.

**Is there a tool/browser there that I can use to browse through my file structure quicker?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at UnixTree

> UnixTree is a powerful and versatile console-mode filemanager for Unix and Linux systems, modeled very closely after the distinguished DOS program XTreeGold.

See http://www.unixtree.org/